# Android "Cannot resolve all dependencies for configuration" SignalR Client

Tags: java, android, websocket, signalr

Why it cannot find websockets? Isn't that built in to Java SDK?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think it's built in? Have you tried searching the web for more information? And don't post screenshots of errors - they're hard to read and inefficient. Cut and paste the text, and give more information about your project, and you will be more likely to get answers.

Comment: Including sites like *imgur* are sometimes closed in enterprise's network, in such environments images cannot be seen at all.